# Install pydrill in Docker image

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip, alpine-linux

I have this docker file based on `alpine` that installs several packages with `conda`. At the end installs `pydrill` with `pip` as there's no `conda` installation.

```
from jcrist/alpine-dask

RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda update -n base -c defaults conda -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda update dask
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install -c conda-forge dask-ml
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install scikit-learn -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install flask -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install waitress -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install gunicorn -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install pytest -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install apscheduler -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install matplotlib -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install pyodbc -y

USER root
RUN apk update
RUN apk add py-pip
RUN pip install pydrill
```

When I build the docker image everything works fine. But when I run the container the command line starts `gunicorn`, but it fails with the following message:

```
  File "/code/app/service/cm/exec/run_drill.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pydrill.client import PyDrill
   
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrill'
```

Is this `pip` installation correct? This is the docker compose:

```
version: "3.0"
services:

  web:
    image: img-dask
    volumes:
      - vol_py_code:/code
      - vol_dask_data:/data
      - vol_dask_model:/model
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    working_dir: /code
    environment:
      - app.config=/code/conf/py.app.json
      - common.config=/code/conf/py.common.json     
    entrypoint:
      - /opt/conda/bin/gunicorn
    command:
      - -b 0.0.0.0:5000
      - --reload
      - app.frontend.app:app


 scheduler:
    image: img-dask
    ports:
      - "8787:8787"
      - "8786:8786"
    entrypoint:
      - /opt/conda/bin/dask-scheduler

  worker:
    image: img-dask
    depends_on:
      - scheduler
    environment:
      - PYTHONPATH=/code
      - MODEL_PATH=/model/rfc_model.pkl
      - PREPROCESSING_PATH=/model/data_columns.pkl
      - SCHEDULER_ADDRESS=scheduler
      - SCHEDULER_PORT=8786
    volumes:
      - vol_py_code:/code
      - vol_dask_data:/data
      - vol_dask_model:/model
    entrypoint:
      - /opt/conda/bin/dask-worker
    command:
      - scheduler:8786
      
volumes:
  vol_py_code:
     name: vol_py_code
  vol_dask_data:
     name: vol_dask_data
  vol_dask_model:
     name: vol_dask_model
```

**UPDATE**

If I run the command line inside the container, I can see that pydrill is installed, but my code does not see the library.

```
/code/conf # pip3 list
Package    Version  
---------- ---------
certifi    2020.12.5
chardet    4.0.0    
idna       2.10     
pip        18.1     
pydrill    0.3.4    
requests   2.25.1   
setuptools 40.6.2   
urllib3    1.26.4   
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 21.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Have you tried to `/opt/conda/bin/pip install pydrill` instead of `pip install pydrill`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that pydrill and all other conda packages are in different environments. When the server starts, it doesn't see pydrill, only conda packages.

To fix the issue install pip itself in conda's environment:

```
from jcrist/alpine-dask

USER root
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda create -p /pyenv -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install -p /pyenv dask scikit-learn flask waitress gunicorn \
    pytest apscheduler matplotlib pyodbc -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install -p /pyenv -c conda-forge dask-ml -y
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda install -p /pyenv pip -y
RUN /pyenv/bin/pip install pydrill
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `conda install pip` instead of `apk`

Something like

```
from jcrist/alpine-dask
WORKDIR /opt/conda/bin

RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda -y
RUN conda update dask
RUN install -c conda-forge dask-ml 
RUN conda install stickit-learn flask waitress gunicorn \
    pytest apscheduler matplotlib pydobc pip -y
RUN pip install pydrill
```

Comment: When I build the image I get this:  > `[3/7] RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda -y:
#6 0.227 /bin/sh: conda: not found`

Comment: Now I'm getting there, on the last line I got ` > [6/6] RUN pip install pydrill:
#9 0.254 /bin/sh: pip: not found`

Comment: Hmm, weird; really weird? and the previous line installs the pip successfully, right?

Comment: see the update, if I log into the container I see pydrill installed

Comment: Can you send the rest of the docker file please?

Comment: In docker console I start gunicorn in conda, maybe that's the issue? `/opt/conda/bin/gunicorn`

Comment: I updated the questions, added the complete docker compose

Comment: I install pydrill with user `root`, maybe it's changing the environment where pydrill is installed? I need user root otherwise pip doesn't work in alpine

Comment: Yeah the root user's pip and the user's pip are different, you should be using the same environment when you are installing and running the code.

Comment: how do you determine the python environment in Dockerfile?

Comment: Just like you'd do it normally, just activate it; I think conda has it's own activation command

Comment: I don't find a way to do this, just activating throws an error saying that `conda init` needs to be called, but I cannot call it in alpine

Comment: I'm drawing a blank too then, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I have packaged `pydrill` for [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pydrill), so you can simply `conda install -c conda-forge pydrill`.